# Conditional entropy to predict a outcome

Tags: probability, entropy

I have given the dataset of three different customers: $A,B,C$ visiting a restaurant which sells $4$ different kind of dishes: $B1, B2, B3, B4$.

The table shows past orders of each of the three customers  (o$1 \to$ o$10$) where o$1$ means first order and o$2$ means second order and so on. How can conditional probability help us here to predict the next order for each of the following customers?

customer/order: o$10$   o$9$  o$8$  o$7$  o$6$  o$5$  o$4$  o$3$  o$2$  o$1$

$A$:    $B1$  $B2$  $B2$  $B2$  $B2$  $B2$  $B1$  $B1$  $B1$  $B1$

$B$:   $B3$  $B2$  $B4$  $B1$  $B3$  $B2$  $B1$  $B3$  $B2$  $B4$

$C$:   $B4$  $B2$  $B1$  $B2$  $B4$  $B3$  $B4$  $B2$  $B4$  $B2$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_{j, i}$ denote the dish $B_j$ at the $i$th order.

Applying Markov chain model per customer, we can compute conditional probabilites as below.

For A, 
$$
P(B_{1,i+1}|B_{1,i}) = \frac{P(B_{1,i+1}, B_{1, i})}{P(B1_i)} = \frac{3 / 9}{4 / 9} \\
P(B_{2,i+1}|B_{1,i}) = \frac{1 / 9}{4 / 9}\\
P(B_{3,i+1}|B_{1,i}) = P(B_{4,i+1}|B_{1,i}) = 0
$$
For B, $P(B_{1,i+1}|B_{3,i}) = 2/2 = 1$, $P(B_{2,i+1}|B_{3,i}) = P(B_{3,i+1}|B_{3,i}) = P(B_{4,i+1}|B_{3,i}) = 0$

For C, $P(B_{2,i+1}|B_{4,i}) = 2/3$, $P(B_{3,i+1}|B_{4,i}) = 1/3$, $P(B_{1,i+1}|B_{4,i}) = P(B_{4,i+1}|B_{4,i}) = 0$

Conditional entropy for A is
$$
\begin{align}
H(B_{*, i+1}|B_{*, i}) & = - \sum_{j, k} P(B_{j,(i+1)}, B_{k,i}) \log \frac{P(B_{j,(i+1)}, B_{k,i})}{P(B_{k,i})} \\
& = - \left( Q(B_{1, i+1}|B_{1, i}) + Q(B_{2, i+1}|B_{1, i}) + Q(B_{1, i+1}|B_{2, i}) + Q(B_{2, i+1}|B_{2, i}) \right) \\
& = - \left( \frac{3}{9}\log\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{5} + \frac{4}{9}\log\frac{4}{5} \right)\\
& \approx 0.53
\end{align}
$$
, where $Q(B_{j,(i+1)}, B_{k,i}) = P(B_{j,(i+1)}, B_{k,i}) \log \frac{P(B_{j,(i+1)}, B_{k,i})}{P(B_{k,i})} $

For B,
$$
\begin{align}
H(B_{*, i+1}|B_{*, i}) & = - \left( \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{9}\log\frac{3}{3} +  \frac{2}{9}\log\frac{2}{2} + \frac{2}{9}\log\frac{2}{2} \right) \\
& \approx 0.15
\end{align}
$$
For C,
$$
\begin{align}
H(B_{*, i+1}|B_{*, i}) & = - \left( \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{9}\log\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{1} + \frac{2}{9}\log\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{9}\log\frac{1}{3} \right)\\
& \approx 0.46
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you help me relate all these probabilities to their conditional entropies?

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you help me one last time. How can we most accurately predict the next order from each of the people using record of other participants using mutual information?